# inserting data into Mongoose nested object

Tags: mongoose

How can I insert data into mongoose nested objects? I keep getting the error that my ref collection is not defined! Here is my code where I'm trying to insert data into the `address` object and `companyId`

```
var companySchema = new Schema({
company_Id :{
    type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : recruiter,
    optional : true
},    
address : {
  country : {
      type : String,
      required : true
  },
  city :{
     type : String,
     required : true
  },
  street: {
     type : String,
     required : true
  }
}
```

Comment: You should read the documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 0):

you are using variable instead of compiled model name
try this

```
var recruiterSchema = new Schema({
    // some fields
})

mongoose.model("Recruiter", recruiterSchema); // same model name here

var companySchema = new Schema({
    company_Id :{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "Recruiter" // and here
    }
    // some fields
})

mongoose.model("Company", companySchema);
```

Comment: Yes,I did exactly the same thing but  I'm have an error message that Recruiter is not defined.